# Oracle Apex interactive report link to other report

Tags: oracle-apex

I have two tables and two classic reports in my application. I would like to update report2 (right site) and the table content depending on a link in report1 (left side).

Scenario:

User clicks on a link inside the columns ID, eg.g "test01".

Data in report2 is updated and shows only the data of table2 where
ID(table1) == ID(table2)

[image]

I created a sample page (page 4):

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=4000:1:107157186133226::NO:RP:FB_FLOW_ID,F4000_P1_FLOW,P0_FLOWPAGE,RECENT_PAGES:107375,107375,107375

workspace:test07032022

User:demo07

PW:sodemo07032022

I know how to set a column as link but I don't know how to get the two reports communicate with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at page #5 (I copied your page 4 to it); it contains modifications:

1st report:

- added hidden page item `P5_SELECTED_ID`
- added virtual column ("Link")
- it is a link to the same page, and sets `P5_SELECTED_ID` to 1st report's `ID` column value

2nd report:

- added `WHERE` clause:

  ```
  id = :P5_SELECTED_ID or :P5_SELECTED_ID is null
  ```
- page items to submit: `P5_SELECTED_ID`

---

That's all; run the page, click "here" to refresh the 2nd report.

Comment: This works, thanks a lot! Only problem is after clicking on the link the page jumps to the top and I have several reports. So the two reports are at the end of the page and that's confusing for the user. Any possibility to go automatically back to the report?

Comment: Move them up :) Just kidding. Unfortunately, I wouldn't know how to do that. I *presume* JavaScript or something like that might help, but I'm not good at it.